# How to add empty_label in forms.ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

For instance, I have this code. How can I add the empty_label to the field Select.

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['choice',]
        widgets = {
            'choice': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'class'}, ??empty_label='lorem'??),
        }
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey('Another Model', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you please share the `Model` (or at least the `choice` field)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameter of the *form field*, not the *widget*. If you do not want to override the rest of the form field, you specify this in the constructor of the form:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].empty_label = 'lorem'

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['choice',]
        widgets = {
            'choice': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'class'}),
        }
```